# Best software raid /filesystem for samba on linux

Tags: raid, samba, zfs, access-control-list, btrfs

I am running ubuntu 16.04 server and need to store files for a samba file server on a software raid. There are 4 500GB SSDs and stability / redundance / iops are of utmost importance.
I tried running zfs on linux for a while but samba acl settings and zfs seem to not be running stable together. With ext4 everything is fine.

Which software raid solution would you recommend? Does btrfs handle acls the same as ntfs? Or is mdadm raid5 with ext4 the safer bet? Any other solution worth mentioning?

A raid card is no option due to cost - there is no additional budget for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's frustrating to see posts from people/organizations who can't afford or budget for the **basics** to protect their data...

If you need a RAID controller, get a RAID controller. You should be able to obtain one since they're available at all price points. Most server-class systems available today have some RAID options. It's a very low barrier.

I'm not sure what question you're asking, though...

ZFS on Linux can run the backend of a Samba share just fine. Perhaps details about what *didn't* work in your previous experience would help here.

Is there a reason you're not using Windows for this?

If ext4 is what you are happy with and you need a software RAID, you could run [ext4 on a ZFS zvol](https://serverfault.com/a/617791/13325), giving you the ACL and permissions you need, coupled with ZFS volume management.

You could also just use old-school mdadm.

Comment: First I tried just using it without any modifications which caused profiles not being readable after a while which I found out being due to zfs handling acls differently. Then I tried mounting it in acl passthrough mode which resulted in the zfs volume locking up and not showing any permissions at all after a few days.
Windows also comes down to cost and know how - I never handled a microsoft server.
ext4 on ZFS seems interesting, I will take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: For zfs, set `xattr=sa` and `acltype=posixacl` on the ZFS filesystem.

Comment: I already use those settings, together with aclinherit=passthrough.